# Magento order export import crashes 500 internal error

Tags: magento-1.9

When I want to transfer my orders and customer details to the new environment we've build I get an error that I cannot define.

When pressing import the system redirects me to a 500 internal error in the browser.

Where do I find the error logs to find out where this is going wrong? I cannot find the problem anywhere.

Comment: This can help you: [Where can I find error log files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834583/where-can-i-find-error-log-files)

Run this command in the command line of your server: 
`lsof |grep log |grep php`

Comment: you should be able to find the report in var/report